# How to declare and instantiate structures of iterators that point to structures of data

Tags: c++, templates

I have a tree of data containers and I'd like to be able to instantiate N iterator references into this tree.

e.g. Given something like this

```
struct DataSource
{
    vector <int>    one;
    vector <bool>   two;
    // ...
    vector <DataSource2>; // (its a tree) 
} d;
```

What I'd like to do now is instantiate iterators into this data structure.   ie I'd like to be able to write something like

```
iterators<DataSource> iter1(d);  
iterators<DataSource> iter2(d);
```

And have this instantiate a parallel data structure with the iterators initialized into their respective vectors.

I then should be able to query and move the iterators:

```
cout << *iter1.one
```

The key is that I only want one definition for the structure of the data and the iterator instances are independent of the data.

I can use partial specialization to instantiate the DataSource elements as either containers or iterators.  e.g. The idea being that b selects either iterators or containers:

```
template <template <typename> class V, bool b>
struct ContainerOrIteratorStruct
{ 
    ContainerOrIterator <int,b> one;
    ContainerOrIterator <bool,b> two;
}

template <class T> using Vec = vector<T, std::allocator<T>>;
ContainerOrIteratorStruct<Vec, false> data(a1);  // <--- here is data
ContainerOrIteratorStruct<Vec, true> iterators(a1); // <--- here are iterators
```

This allows me to instantiate the parallel types, but doesn't solve the initialization part... ie since the source and the iterator structures are so parallel types I should be able to get the compiler to initialize the iterators into the data source.

Comment: If you have three hundred vectors in a single class, you probably have a design problem, by the way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to iterate over? The members of your `struct`?

Comment: @AndyG yeah, the three hundred was just meant as a hint to the problem: I don't want to replicate the structure more than once.   The real data structure doesn't have 300 elements in a single struct.  The real thing is more complex tree of data where the root points to 10 say and then fans down.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The iterator struct is to maintain iterators into each element of the struct.  e.g. there should be a member iterator called 'one' that points to an integer in the vector called one.  there should be another iterator called 'two' that is an iterator into the vector called two...
I'm not necessarily trying to walk between the members of my struct.  (eg visit(one) visit(two).  Then again, maybe I need to also iterate this way to set them up.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. You should try to implement your own solution and ask more focused questions when you encounter actual problems. You are unlikely to get an out-of-the-box solution here, with such an open question.

Comment: A tip, you won't be able to infer the number, name or types of a `struct`'s members. At some point, you will have to enumerate them. Perhaps variadic templates, [std::integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and a [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of member pointers will be helpful in saving and iterating over a list of members.